# winform c# datetimepicker how to set default time to 00:00:00

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Here is the code to set the time when the datetimepicker value changed

```
    private void o_start_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        o_start.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";

        o_start.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " 00:00:00");
    }
```

but the winforms still display 12:00:00 after i picked the date, anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Both answers you have are correct, however none of them notes you can set the value simply to `System.DateTime.Today` - like this: `o_start.Value = System.DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in the custom format the hours part:

```
o_start.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Notice the capital `HH`

**Edit**

Although it was not in your question, as @ZoharPeled mentioned in his comment,  you can initialize your `DateTimePicker` using `Today` property of `System.DateTime`:

```
o_start.Value = System.DateTime.Today;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a 24 hour format the hour should be HH and not hh

```
o_start.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```